How to customize Split window width from 100% in Android Studio
At the morning when I started my Android Studio and continue to work, by mistake I made Preview window width 100% (for Split Mode). I have searched for lot of answeres but no one is showing me the exact reason.
Here is my problem:
See Image : Full width preview window
Here I have found a simple solution and will showing you how to get rid out of it.
Step-1: Click on Project/Directory icon on the top left side bar of Android studio and you will see below mentioned screen
See Image : Project/Directory structure is hideen
Step-2: Now scroll your mouse cursor to the starting of Android studio and move until you can see size customization cursor and slide to right side to open Code View. As seen into image:
See Image : View is expanded
Enjoy! now you can see both the palletes (code & preview) size by side.
Feel free to reach out if you are facing the same problem.
